# Connect to Raspberry pi through Wifi

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-zero-w, access-point, dhcpcd

I'm currently trying to do something that's quite hard for me.

I have a raspberry pi zero w that's running an apache server.

I want to be able to access my pi anywhere, even offline by connecting to it from for example my androids wifi tab.

I have seen a lot of tutorials showing how to create an Access Point on the Raspberry Pi but they use dhcpcd.service, and my pi doesn't have dhcpcd.

If I try installing dhcpcd5, it wants to uninstall network-pi, bluetooth-pi and something else.

How do I do this?

Comment: `it wants to uninstall network-pi, bluetooth-pi` are they the EXACT package names it wants to uninstall? They don't seem to be actual packages

Comment: By the way, I'd have though you'd need a DHCP server for an Access Point, not a DHCP client (which is what dhcpcd5 is) - sure, you may need to tweak some settings in dhcpcd when creating an access point, but that's not an issue if you somehow don't have that

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Raspberry Pi 4, Raspberry Pi 3, and Raspberry Pi Zero W can host a wireless network using the built-in wireless module. Raspberry Pi models that lack a built-in module support this functionality using a separate wireless dongle.

Assuming you are using one of the above models, you can enable a hotspot with

```
sudo nmcli device wifi hotspot ssid <example-network-name> password <example-password>
```

([Ref](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#host-a-wireless-network-on-your-raspberry-pi))

If you use the newest Raspberry Pi OS image (bookworm), you can even enable a hotspot from the UI! Here is a short video that shows how: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L4ArdfS87j8

Once you connect to the hotspot, you will have to know the IP address of the gateway to type into your browser to connect to the pi server. The default for this seems to be `10.42.0.1`.